# Syntax Error when try to call sklearn_genetic

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, genetic-algorithm

After Installing sklearn-genetic-opt
I tried to call it with this code

```
from sklearn_genetic import GASearchCV
from sklearn_genetic.space import Continuous
from sklearn_genetic.plots import plot_fitness_evolution, plot_search_space
```

But I got this Syntax Error, and I don't have an idea what is that

```
  File c:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:3398 in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  Input In [9] in <cell line: 26>
    from sklearn_genetic import GASearchCV

  File c:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sklearn_genetic\__init__.py:1 in <module>
    from .genetic_search import GASearchCV, GAFeatureSelectionCV

  File c:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sklearn_genetic\genetic_search.py:6 in <module>
    from deap import base, creator, tools

  File c:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\deap\base.py:192
    raise TypeError, ("Both weights and assigned values must be a "
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am new to Python, can you help me define what error is this?

Comment: You seem to have a Python 2 version of `deap` for some reason.

Comment: Looking at the source code and issue tracker on Github, it looks like they depend on the no-longer-supported `use_2to3` functionality of setuptools. `deap` doesn't appear to be actively maintained any more, so it doesn't seem likely that this will get fixed.

Comment: @Dedy Darmawan. Could you please provide some code to show where this is coming from ("Both weights and assigned values must be a"). Something appears to be missing for the brace bracket at the end.

Comment: Update: I solved this issue by downgrade my python version from 3.10 to 3.8. I don't know why, but sklearn-genetic-opt seems not compatible with setuptools in newest version of python

Comment: It looks like you're using python 3.10, which is not supported by deap, and therefore not supported in sklearn-genetic-opt, try using some virtual env with a version 3.9

Comment: Just an update, the package now supports python 3.10+

Comment: now python 3.11 is also supported